# show that a function is well defined

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Show that function series $f(x)= \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$

is defined and continues over $\mathbb{R}$.

The question is confusing me because usually we study the convergence of a function series using [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) as

$\forall n\geq 1, ~ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $,

$\big| \frac{1}{n^2+x^2} \big| \leq M_n= \frac{1}{n^2} $ and $ \sum_{n\geq 1} M_n \leq \infty $ using the definition of Riemann series so $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$ converges.

How could this help in studying if the function is defined and continues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By M-test the series converges **uniformly**. This means the partial sums of the series converge unifomly to the infinite sum $f$. Since the partial sums are continuous functions and uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Excuse me, I am a little confused about the general procedure I should follow to prove that the function is well defined and continuous. According to what I understood from your answer, Always, I should start proving that the function series converges uniformly then to use theorem $1$ in the link
http://mathonline.wikidot.com/continuity-of-the-sum-of-a-uniformly-convergent-series-of-fu

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggested.